# Casting subclasses extending the same original class

Tags: java, casting, subclass

How can I cast two extends class like that in java?

```
    class B extends Object{

    }

    class C extends Object{

    }

    B b = new B();

    C c = (C)b;//Cannot cast from B to C
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't.  Consider a slight rename:

```
class Ford extends Car {

}
class Chevrolet extends Car {

}

Ford ford = new Ford();

Chevrolet chevrolet = (Chevrolet) ford;
```

Both are, however, a Car so you can say

```
Car car = ford;
```

but not any more than that.

Answer (score 6):

You can't cast an object `B` to `C`, because `B` is not a `C`, the best you can infer is that it's an `Object`. Here's another analogy:

```
class Animal {
    public void eat();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark();
}

public Cat extends Animal {
    public void meow();
}
```

Say you have:

```
Cat sprinkles = new Cat();

// this doesn't make sense
Dog aDog = (Dog) sprinkles;
aDog.bark(); // can't do this because sprinkles can't bark()

// but this does
Animal myCat = (Animal) sprinkles;
myCat.eat(); // but it can eat()
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come is to use interfaces

```
 class B extends Object implements Thing {}
 class C extends Object implements Thing {} 

 B b = new B()
 Thing c = (Thing)b
```

As others have indicated you cannot do what you are trying with just classes.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that since `b` is not an instance of class C. It is only possible to cast an object into a super-class or a super-interface.

Answer (score 1):

You categorically cannot do that.  You can only cast if the type to which you are casting actually represents the ancestry of the target.  In this case, `B` simply is not an instance of `C` (and vice versa).  The real question is why would you want to?  And what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

In the given code, class `B` and class `C` are not in a "is-a" relationship, so they cannot be casted to each other.

The only thing that `B` and `C` has in common is that they are both subclasses of `Object`, therefore, they can both be casted to `Object`. In otherwords, `B` is-a `Object` and `C` is-a `Object`:

```
B b = new B();
Object ob = (Object)b;

C c = new C();
Object oc = (Object)c;
```

---

As a counterexample to what is being done, imagine this case:

```
class B extends Object {
    public void doSomething();
}

class C extends Object {
    public void doAnotherThing();
}
```

In this case, what is the following code supposed to do?

```
C realC = new C();
realC.doSomething();   // This is OK.

B c = (B)realC;
c.doSomething();       // ???
```

Since the object made from class `C` doesn't have a `doSomething` method, what would it do?
It can be seen that just because `B` and `C` have a common ancestor does not mean that they can be interchangeable with each other.

Therefore, what is attempted in the code above cannot be performed.

Answer (score 1):

but...giving this hierarchy
`class X {}`
`class Z extends X{}`
`class Y extends  X{}`
`X z = new Z();`
`X y = new Y();`
`Z y2 =(Z)y;`
Why is alloweb by the compiler the casting between Z and Y? It not works at runtime obviously cos Z is not a Y.