# Interface cast two classes

Tags: java, android

I have two classes with similar structure. For some good reasons, I have to have two different classes.

```
class FooA {
   Public String Name;
}

class FooB {
   Public String Name;
}
```

I want to cast FooA to FooB object.

```
FooA a = new FooA().setName("StackOverFlow is Great");
FooB b = (FooB)a;
```

Currently, I am deep copying i.e. creating an instance and assigning the values from one to another.

```
FooB b = (FooB)a.getFooB();
```

Another option I was exploring was using Interface but I experienced some issues in typecasting.

```
interface IA {
  String Name;
}

class FooA implements IA {
    Public String Name;
}

class FooB implements IA {
   Public String Name;
}

FooA a = new FooA().setName("let's try this");
FooB b = ((FooB) (IA)a);
```

And Can't use abstract class.

Pleas suggest a better approach.

Thanks
Raj

Comment: You cannot cast `FooA` to `FooB` because they are not in the same inheritance tree. One of them should be inherited from another in order to cast them.

Comment: I know that but I want to transform one object into another. And that's why I am asking whether interface would be a right approach.

Comment: @RajLalwani: of couse not. this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast FooA to FooB. You can do as following

```
IA a = new FooA();
 a. setName("let's try this")

IA b = (FooB) a
```

But it will ultimately create Classcast exception at runtime. 
So its better to use one as a super class and other extending the earlier

Answer (score 2):

You should extend one class from another and then you can cast to the more general class. The other advantage is, that you can override specific behavior as needed.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that jumps to mind is a mapper:

```
public FooA mapFooBToFooA(FooB original){
  FooA result = new FooA();
  result.setName(original.getName());
  return result;
}
```

bu you can't directly cast them, since they are not in one inheritance tree.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I am doing at the moment. Wanted to know whether there are better and wiser ways.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast `FooA` to `FooB` because they are not in the same inheritance tree. One of them should be inherited from another in order to cast it.

Here is the good [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798663/casting-subclasses-extending-the-same-original-class) with a good example:

You can't. Consider a slight rename:

```
class Ford extends Car { }
class Chevrolet extends Car { }

Ford ford = new Ford();
Chevrolet chevrolet = (Chevrolet) ford;
```

It looks wrong, right?

However, you can inherit from a single interface. You **won't be able cast `FooA` to `FooB` as well but you will be able to work with both classes through the interface:

```
interface Car
{
    void Run();
}

class Ford extends Car { /* */ }
class Chevrolet extends Car { /* */ }

Car myCar = new Ford();
myCar.Run();

myCar = new Chevrolet();
myCar.Run();
```

Comment: Mate, I can't have that. One of the classes is auto-generated by ORM.

Comment: @RajLalwani You should inherit one class from another or use interfaces. Or you have to change architecture and remove one of classes (use the single class everywhere). If you can't do either of this, use deep copy. In your case, it is probably the best solution.

Comment: Yes. that's seems like an option. I am trying to inherit from ORM generated class. I want to keep them different for future complexities.